# How to extract desired pattern from file name using bash?

Tags: excel, bash

I have two columns in excel sheet. Column one has the name of the cell and the columns two has its value.

In column I have several cells with the same name. Now what I want is based on the Column 1 cell number I would like to group all the values in single cell (new column). And then find out the unique numbers in that group.

I have n number of files inside a folder. I was able to list the existing files with *.log extension.

my filenames are as follows:

```
BV996-1-Positive.log
BV997-1-Positive.log
EV10-1-Negative.log
EV10-1-Positive.log
EV10-2-Negative.log
EV10-2-Positive.log
```

This what I wrote so far:

```
for file in davinci_final_240/*.log
do
echo "$(basename "$file")"
done
```

How can I exclude "-*tive.log" part from these files.

Comment: FYI `basename` can remove a *fixed* suffix itself: `basename "$file" .log` returns, for example, `BV996-1-Positive`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To exclude everything after the final dash, use something like `base=${file%-*}`

```sh
for f in davinci_final_240/*.log
do
  file=${f##*/}
  echo "${file%-*}"
done
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Is it possible to take one outcome ata time from list of files ??

Comment: Yes: the inner part of the loop does exactly that. Do your per-file processing inside the loop.